# How to evaluate difference between RGB numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm building a software for a LED Canvas with 24 x 30 pixels.
And I want to save the current state in a numpy array, then get a new state as a numpy array and slowly fade from the first state to the second state.

To do so I was thinking i have to compare my two numpy arrays:

```
currentState = np.zeros((24,30,3), 'int_') # All LEDs off e.g.
newState = np.zeros((24,30,3), 'int_') + 255 # All LEDS full white
```

Now i need an array with the difference between each item on the matrix like

```
currentState[x][y] = [0, 0, 0]
newState[x][y] = [255, 255, 255]
# Some compare operation
difference[x][y] = [255, 255, 255]

# or e.g.

currentState[x][y] = [255, 70, 30]
newState[x][y] = [100, 255, 30]
# Some compare operation
difference[x][y] = [-155, 185, 0]
```

Since execution time is crutial i don't wanna iterate over the matrix arrays. Is there any other way?

Thanks a lot in advance.

The answer is not currentState - newState. Please look carefully on the second example.

Comment: `newState - currentState`

Comment: Can you please unmark as duplicate. It's not the same issue. Look at the second example i gave... the simple subtract does not work for that.

it would be difference[x][y] = [155, - 115, 0] -> Not what I need!

Comment: How would you get that if you subtract `currentState` from `newState`?  `100-255 = -155`, `255-70=185`, and `30-30=0`.  You're subtracting in the wrong order

Comment: You are totally right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally just subtract them:

```
difference = newState - currentState
```

Comment: Look at the second example i gave. This would not work:
```
currentState[x][y] = [255, 70, 30]
newState[x][y] = [100, 255, 30]
# Some compare operation
difference[x][y] = [-155, 185, 0]
```

Comment: @stackcrossiflow Did you try it? I did and it works.

Comment: You are totally right, sorry!